# How do I run Headless Chrome in a Shell on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have read a little bit about Headless-Chrome and the Puppeteer API that Google has developed.  I have seen a few answers on Stack Overflow so far about running Headless Chrome, and I also know all about Selenium for Testing Web-Pages and Scraping Web-Pages.  I have written an HTML Parser, Search and Update Package myself, but I often run into problems when there is Java-Script on a web-page that has data I am trying to parse and retrieve.

According to Google's Documentation, Headless Chrome has been supported on Google Cloud Platform Shell (A Linux/Debian/BSD Type of UNIX Command Line, similar to Amazon Web Services).  Today, I attempted to download a web-page using a simple Headless Chrome command line, but the Shell returned an error to me as follows:

```
@cloudshell:~$ chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://sepehr.irib.ir/?idc=32&idt=tv&idv=1
```

I typed this in an instance of the BASH Shell on GCP, and received this error.

```
[1] 498
[2] 499
bash: chrome: command not found
[2]+  Done                    idt=tv
```

The URL above is just a URL from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981583/jsoup-can-not-pars-javascript-what-should-i-do).  I was just toying around to see if I could answer it.  It is a very commonly asked type of "Web Scraping" question I read on the Web-Scraping tag.  It's not too important (not to me, but probably to the OP it might be!)  According to a few YouTube Videos, the **Google Chrome Headless JSON API** allows users to start an instance of Chrome such that it functions like a **PaaS**, not a UI that can be viewed.  This seems pretty nice, and I am fully aware that Selenium Web-Scraping Technology has already taken advantage of this service.   HOWEVER, I would just like to start ***accessing the JSON API from Java*** - without using Selenium - primarily to see if I can understand it, and to, hopefully, begin making JSON requests (in Java) to a Headless Chrome from a Google Cloud Shell instance without adding all the complexity of the Java Selenium Package.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732991/possible-to-run-headless-chrome-chromium-in-a-google-cloud-function) (and answers) seems to be a "partial duplicate" of my question, unfortunately the Google Help Pages state that since 2019 the service has become fully supported - and the answers here are from 2018.  I suspect I should not have to perform a COMPLETE BUILD of Chrome in order to run a headless Chrome instance from the Command Line, but I could be wrong.  In any case, newer answers to reflect 2019 and 2020 work done by Google Devs would help - and, more importantly, I would like to use "Plain Old Java Objects" to query the Browser, rather than using `Pupeteer` and `Node.JS`.  I can deal with `JSON` very well in Java.

> **Is there a BASH 'sudo' command that I may use to get an instance
>   of `Chrome` running in the Shell of GCP?**

I have reviewed the suggested duplicates of this question, and do not know what to do... :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to install headless chrome on your Cloud Shell. Here the script

```
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
export DISPLAY=:99.0
sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libappindicator1 fonts-liberation libasound2 libgconf-2-4 libnspr4 libxss1 libnss3 xdg-utils
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

Then run your command. Don't forget to surround your URL with double quote `"` because the `&` run another thread in linux

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom "https://sepehr.irib.ir/?idc=32&idt=tv&idv=1"
```

I got some errors that I fixed with this command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Thanks-you, I would really like this to work.  I know plenty of UNIX commands, but I'll admit I don't know everything.  When I type the `xvfb` line (From Answer Above), I get the error that Google Cloud Shell cannot find it.  It just says `sh: /etc/init.d/xvfb: No such file or directory`  Do I need to "docker" or "sudo" something to get it?  Also, the line `sudo apt-get update` breaks too.  It just says `W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-stretch-prod/dists/stret`  If you have time, let me know...

Comment: Are you on Cloud Shell? I performed my test on this environment. (your first line of code example lead me to Cloud Shell!)

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Cloud Shell with the "Theia" Interface.  I have been doing all the development (in Java) using that.  I have an HTML Parser.  I was not able to successfully `apt-get` any of those programs or tools.  Are you familiar with Cloud Shell in GCP?  Do you use it?  My `instance` as they call it does not have the directories identified in your answer...

Comment: I would like, also, to know if you have used the "Headless Chrome" CDP JSON interface.  I would like to attempt some simple JSON requests of my own, without using `Selenium` and without learning Node.JS (`Pupeteer`).  If you have ever used the CDP Headless Chrome API yourself, let me know what you think about it.